# Country, city and town

Tags: prestashop

I want that the form shown to the user for specifying the address contains several drop down menus for countries, cities and towns. Right now, there are drop down menus for countries and states. In my prestashop, the drop down menu for states contains the cities of the selected country.

is there any good way to do it without having to include a module with charge?
I've searched too much and I don't find a solution for this.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the towns in the cities dropdown (and to be managed as states). A separate dropdown for the towns will require additional programming, which mean - paid module. I doubt if such module exists (separate dropdowns for cities and towns).

Comment: Yes, this solution is given in other posts, but it's not considered a good solution since it mix cities and towns at the same dropdown. I think I will need to modify the code. Thanks anyway!!